# Pillow module error, issue updating modules

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I worked on a project for which I needed to update my python. Now I cannot get my old projects to run. I don't have a good understanding on how all the packages are working.

I get the following error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\wiedb\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-12-17_5.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\wiedb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\wiedb\Anaconda3\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
  File "C:\Users\wiedb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\wiedb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
  File "C:\Users\wiedb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\wiedb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 13, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
  File "C:\Users\wiedb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\wiedb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
  File "C:\Users\wiedb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 90, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

Comment: My suggestion would be: don't install any additional packages into conda's base environment (https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-environments), read up on Python virtual environments (https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/), create a new environment and install the dependencies for your Kivy project to that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will install all dependencies of Kivy.

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy.deps.angle
pip install --upgrade kivy
```

For PIL error , try updating PILLOW.